# Activity SharedElement return transtion not running after configuration change

Tags: android, android-activity, material-components-android, android-transitions

Sharedelement return transition does not run after a configuration changed.
A -> B and B -> A works fine if there is no configuration changed, but after configuration changed B -> A does not run. The shareelementcallback does not get triggered. B is a full screen activity

Activity A

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setExitSharedElementCallback(MaterialContainerTransformSharedElementCallback())

        fab.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,NoteActivity::class.java)
            val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                this, it, "note"
            )
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
        }
    }
}
```

Activity B

```kotlin
class NoteActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_note) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "note")
        setEnterSharedElementCallback(MaterialContainerTransformSharedElementCallback())
        window.sharedElementEnterTransition = createTransform(true)
        window.sharedElementReturnTransition = createTransform(false)
    }

    private fun createTransform(enter: Boolean): MaterialContainerTransform {
        return MaterialContainerTransform(this, enter)
            .apply {
                addTarget(android.R.id.content)
                duration = resources.getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime).toLong()
                val startColor = intent.getIntExtra(COLOR, Color.WHITE)
                val endColor = MaterialColors.getColor(
                    this@NoteActivity,
                    R.attr.colorSurface, Color.WHITE
                )

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(MOTION, false))
                    pathMotion = MaterialArcMotion()

                if (enter) {
                    startContainerColor = startColor
                    endContainerColor = endColor
                } else {
                    startContainerColor = endColor
                    endContainerColor = startColor
                }
            }
    }
}
```